# Best TFS Viewer for a Team Lead

Tags: tfs

Is there a tool that can give you a quick view of all TFS changes across an entire day.

Essentially **rather** than seeing all of the changes **one commit** at a time, I'd like to see all the change done over the day. Essentially the viewer merges all the changes into one view.
*We're using the new VisualStudio.com hosted TFS*

Comment: Isnt the source control explorer's history sufficient in this case or do you need some other data too other than commits?

Answer (score 4):

[Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) is a great tool to use outside of Visual Studio to quickly look at changes and the current status of files.

Here is a breif overview:

- History Sidekick application pane provides the following features:

  View version control tree with files and folders (similar to Source
  Control Explorer) Search item (file or folder) by name and select
  found item in version control tree View selected item history either
  for all users or filtered by user Export history list to CSV file 
  Compare file versions selected in history View selected item
  properties and pending changes View selected item branches tree and
  selected branch properties View selected item merge history; it is
  possible to view separately all merges performed with selected item
  as a merge target (merges to) or with selected item as a source
  (merges from)
- Compare merge target and source file versions in history View
  selected item merge candidates in a tree view; it is possible to
  select single merge source from the list Compare merge candidate file
  version with latest version of target file View selected item labels
  either for all users or filtered by user; the information displayed
  includes item version in label Compare file versions between two
  labels View changeset details supported in all lists containing
  changesets Status Sidekick application pane provides the following
  features:
- View tree of pending changes filtered by specific user name (user may
  be selected from list of valid users), TFS project name  and change
  creation date range View lock icon indication in pending changes tree
  to easily identify locks View detailed list of pending changes in
  selected folder in tree Customize detailed list format and export
  list to CSV file Unlock one or more locked files/folders Undo one or
  more pending changes on files/folders

Answer (score 2):

In the VS "Source Control Explorer", you can right-click a folder and choose "Compare."  In that dialogue, you can choose to compare a Source Control folder to itself, choosing a specific changeset or date for the second instance.  This will give you the diff of what's changed in the last day.

[image]